# NSDictionary leaking memory

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I have a problem with my code that for the life of me I can't figure out, not even with all previous threads here on SO.
I'm pulling data from a JSON source and putting it in an NSDictionary as stated in tutorials and on SO. When profiling the app, I notice a memory leak caused by this NSDictionary but releasing it at the end of this function crashes the app. Any suggestions?
(By the way: I'm new to Obj-C and programming in general, so this code is mostly cherrypicked from various sources.)

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse JSON for empty return
    if([responseData length] != 0){

        NSError* error = nil;
        //Convert JSON data to Obj-C
        NSDictionary* allShotData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSString *player = [[allShotData objectForKey:@"player"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *shotDribbblePage = [allShotData objectForKey:@"url"];

        NSString *shotTitle = [allShotData objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[allShotData objectForKey:@"image_url"]];
        shotPageURL = [shotDribbblePage retain];


        //***********************
        //  Setup a-sync loading of shot
        //***********************

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImage:) object:imageURL];   
        [queue addOperation:operation]; 
        [operation release];
        [queue release];
    }
    else{
        airballCount++;
        if (airballCount <= 20) {
            [self getDribbbleData];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Too many airballs. Bailing out");
            [self showNoConnectionModal];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
shotPageURL = [shotDribbblePage retain];
```

you should probably use the accessor:

```
self.shotPageURL = shotDribbblePage;
```

I should *really* emphasize that you should use your accessors everywhere since they do your ref counting for you (exception: not in initializers and dealloc). As beryllium also notes, you could do your ref counting manually if there is no accessor. That takes the basic form:

```
[shotPageURL release];
shotPageURL = [shotDribbblePage retain];
```

If it's the contents of the returned dictionary that are leaking, then it's how you have used/referenced the contents when read (over-retain).

If you're using your class in a concurrent context, then you will usually need a lock.

If you're loading a `UIImage` or otherwise interacting with UIKit objects from a secondary thread -- that's not good.

Comment: Or `[shotPageURL release]; shotPageURL = nil; shotPageURL = [shotDribbblePage retain];` if there is no property.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that was indeed one of the issues but as it turns out not the only one. One guy mentioned copying the shotDribbblePage by adding copy and releasing it manually afterwards. This did the trick apparently as the red spike doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: @Justin So your suggestion turned out to be the sole issue after all. I couldn't believe that copy/release suggestion would be it so I commented that part out and used beryllium's suggestion. Result: no leaks. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Max ok great. the copy == resolved was a bit odd - i suspected a threading error after reading that. fortunately, it's solved now :)